# Scraping Transfermarket with Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm having trouble scraping Transfermarket. I want to scrape data for the top 5 european leagues (prem league, la liga, serie a, ligue 1, bundesliga) over the past 20 seasons. In this I want to collect a series of details - player name, age, player position, player club, player club left, fee. But even with this very basic code I wrote to scrape just one page of 18/19 prem league transfers collecting teams and names (additions) I get an error I don't understand. I've been using the selector gadget too.

My code:

```
require(rvest)

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/transfers/wettbewerb/GB1/plus/?saison_id=2012&s_w=&leihe=0&leihe=1&intern=0"

scraped_page <- read_html(page)

Team_html  = html_nodes(page, ".tooltipstered+ .tooltipstered") 
Team = html_text(Team_html)
Addition_html = html_nodes(page, ".table-header+ .responsive-table .spielprofil_tooltip")
Addition = html_text(Addition_html)


df <- data.frame(Team, Addition)

head(df)
```

What R Returns:

```
> page = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/transfers/wettbewerb/GB1/plus/?saison_id=2012&s_w=&leihe=0&leihe=1&intern=0"
> 
> scraped_page <- read_html(page)
> 
> Team_html  = html_nodes(page, ".tooltipstered+ .tooltipstered") 
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
> Team = html_text(Team_html)
> Addition_html = html_nodes(page, ".table-header+ .responsive-table .spielprofil_tooltip")
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character"
> Addition = html_text(Addition_html)
> 
> 
> df <- data.frame(Team, Addition)
Error in data.frame(Team, Addition) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 922
> 
> head(df)

1 function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE)    
2 {                                           
3     if (missing(ncp))                       
4         .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)       
5     else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
6 }
```

I was thinking of starting here and then using gsub and some other commands to in a loop cycle through years and leagues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you are having is that

```
 Team_html  = html_nodes(page, ".tooltipstered+ .tooltipstered")
```

Should be

```
 Team_html  = html_nodes(scraped_page, ".tooltipstered+ .tooltipstered")
```

Additonally, I don't think you have correctly specified the selector. I think you might want to do some like this instead...

**Update**

Potential Solution 1:

Separately scrape each table by team, them manually add the team names before you stack the data. In the code below I do this for the first 5 teams

```
in1<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > table') %>% html_table()
in2<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > table') %>% html_table()
in3<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(2) > table') %>% html_table()
in4<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(2) > table') %>% html_table()
in5<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(8) > div:nth-child(2) > table') %>% html_table()

out1<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(4) > table') %>% html_table()
out2<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(4) > table') %>% html_table()
out3<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(4) > table') %>% html_table()
out4<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(4) > table') %>% html_table()
out5<-html_nodes(scraped_page, '#main > div:nth-child(13) > div.large-8.columns > div:nth-child(8) > div:nth-child(4) > table') %>% html_table()

in1<-in1[[1]]
in2<-in2[[1]]
in3<-in3[[1]]
in4<-in4[[1]]
in5<-in5[[1]]

out1<-out1[[1]]
out2<-out2[[1]]
out3<-out3[[1]]
out4<-out4[[1]]
out5<-out5[[1]]

in1$team<-"Arsenal"
in2$team<-"Man U"
in3$team<-"West Brom"
in4$team<-"Fulham"
in5$team<-"New Castle"


out1$team<-"Arsenal"
out2$team<-"Man U"
out3$team<-"West Brom"
out4$team<-"Fulham"
out5$team<-"New Castle"


ins<-rbind(in1,in2,in3,in4,in5)
outs<-rbind(out1,out2,out3,out4,out5)
```

Potential Solution 2 :

This solution does not preserve team names but seams to scarpe more efficiently.

```
tab<-html_nodes(scraped_page, ".responsive-table td") %>% html_text()
temp<-data.frame(value=tab, index=index)
df<-data.frame(x1=character(981), x2=character(981), x3=character(981), x4=character(981), x5=character(981),
               x6=character(981),x7=character(981),x8=character(981),x9=character(981))
for (i in 1:9){
df[,i]<-temp$value[temp$index==i]

}
head(df)
```

Comment: that does help thanks -- but I'm still having trouble getting it to grab data from all teams instead of just the first which Is originally why I thought saving a series of elements i.e. Age, Position, etc be collected as individual columns before being put into a complete data frame would work. When I corrected by above team and playername selectors I still get this error returned too - Error in data.frame(Team, Addition) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 922.

Comment: Your getting that error because Team is empty  I'm can't see what you are trying to grab but the ".tooltipstered+ .tooltipstered" selector is not working.

Comment: I'm trying to grab just the names of the teams -- the text of which seems to be isolated by that

Comment: If you are trying to pull the team names from the table headers then even if you scrape the team name correctly, you will not be able to combine them in a data frame as there will only be one value for each table. You will need to either assign team names by table (as I do in potential solution 1), or manually create a vector of team names and attach them to your final dataset.